# Mascaras no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mask

Gostaria de saber como utilizar o [angular-input-masks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-input-masks). Fiz todos os passos ditos no mesmo, porem não consegui fazer funcionar.

Estou utilizando o AngularJS, aqui esta minha pagina index.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CEP Spec</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../node_modules/angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks-dependencies.js"></script>
 <script src="../node_modules/angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks.br.js"></script>
 <script>
  angular.module('app', ['ui.utils.masks']);
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
 <form name="form" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h2>ui-br-cep-mask</h2>
  <input type="text" name="field17" ng-model="initializedCep" ui-br-cep-mask><br>
  <span ng-bind="initializedCep"></span> - {{form.field17.$error}}<br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="field18" ng-model="cep" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}" ui-br-cep-mask><br>
  <span ng-bind="cep"></span> - {{form.field18.$error}}<br>
  <br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/289825/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código que já tentou e não deu certo!

Comment: Insira a dependência correta: 

   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-input-masks/4.1.0/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-input-masks/4.1.0/angular-input-masks.br.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar em seu navegador, você deve executar o comando:

```
npm run build
```

irá criar um diretório na raiz do projeto com o nome **releases** que conterá um arquivo provavelmente com o nome **angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js**. Você deve remover as linhas:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks-dependencies.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks.br.js"></script>
```

E importar o arquivo gerado:

```
<script src="angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

Ou simplesmente, importe diretamente do repósitorio *NPM*:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-input-masks@4.1.0/releases/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

#### Veja funcionando

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-input-masks@4.1.0/releases/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-input-masks@4.1.0/br.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.utils.masks']);
  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.percentage = 0.45;
  });
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <form name="form" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h2>ui-br-cep-mask</h2>
    <input type="text" name="field17" ng-model="initializedCep" ui-br-cep-mask><br>
    <span ng-bind="initializedCep"></span> - {{form.field17.$error}}<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field18" ng-model="cep" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}" ui-br-cep-mask><br>
    <span ng-bind="cep"></span> - {{form.field18.$error}}<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="percentage" ui-percentage-mask>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito bom, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado..